# Add utterances to a LUIS app using C#

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I'm trying to implement a `C#` code which can add utterances in my `Luis API` like it is showed in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-cs-add-utterance).

So I'm only interested in the function `AddUtterances()` and to test it I put it in the function `ShowLuisResult()` to be sure it will be used each time I send a message to the chatbot but when I take a look in the API I see no utterance is added...

I put the file `utterances.json` at the same place as `BasicLuisDialog.cs` and in `/d/home` in the `kudu` console to be sure it works.

Here is the code :

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Microsoft.Bot.Sample.LuisBot
{
    // For more information about this template visit http://aka.ms/azurebots-csharp-luis
    [Serializable]
    public class BasicLuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
    {

        // NOTE: Replace this example LUIS application ID with the ID of your LUIS application.
        static string appID = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";

        // NOTE: Replace this example LUIS application version number with the version number of your LUIS application.
        static string appVersion = "0.1";

        // NOTE: Replace this example LUIS authoring key with a valid key.
        static string authoringKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        static string host = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com";
        static string path = "/luis/api/v2.0/apps/" + appID + "/versions/" + appVersion + "/";


    public BasicLuisDialog() : base(new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute(
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAppId"], 
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAPIKey"], 
        domain: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAPIHostName"])))
    {
    }

    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task NoneIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
    }

    // Go to https://luis.ai and create a new intent, then train/publish your luis app.
    // Finally replace "Greeting" with the name of your newly created intent in the following handler
    [LuisIntent("Greeting")]
    public async Task GreetingIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
    }

    [LuisIntent("Cancel")]
    public async Task CancelIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
    }

    [LuisIntent("Help")]
    public async Task HelpIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
    }

    private async Task ShowLuisResult(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result) 
    {
        AddUtterances("utterances.json");
        await context.PostAsync($"You have reached {result.Intents[0].Intent}. You said: {result.Query}");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }


    async static Task AddUtterances(string input_file)
    {
        string uri = host + path + "examples";
        string requestBody = File.ReadAllText(input_file);
        var response = await SendPost(uri, requestBody);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendPost(string uri, string requestBody)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
            request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "text/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", authoringKey);
            return await client.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }


}
```

}

And here is the content of `utterances.json` :

```
[
    {
        "text": "go to Seattle",
        "intentName": "Help",
        "entityLabels": []
    },
    {
        "text": "book a flight",
        "intentName": "Greeting",
        "entityLabels": []
    }
]
```

Comment: You did change out the app id and authoring key for your own, correct?

Comment: How exactly you do "I take a look in the API I see no utterance is added..."? Could you confirm there are no changes even if you are logged into https://www.luis.ai/applications/yourAppId/versions/yourVersion/build/intents ?

Comment: @DFBerry Yes, I did. Sorry I didn't mention it.

Comment: @FerdinandFejskid There are no changes. I logged into the API using your link and I changed "yourAppId" and "yourVersion" with mine but I see no difference in the intents and no utterances is added.

Comment: Do you know that the code to update utterances works outside the bot framework? Perhaps in just a console app?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason the Botbuilder tools for Luis are gone from Github as seen that they were here 2 weeks ago -

[Google cache of Luis Bot Builder tools git](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:5CXecAM94vcJ:https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/LUIS+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-b-1-ab)

[Image capture of the git with all functionality of Luis CLI form - no need for full program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNguf.jpg)

I cant post images yet so heres a link to a picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNguf.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your code, but did notice that you are not awaiting the call to AddUtterances from within ShowLuisResult:

```
private async Task ShowLuisResult(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    AddUtterances("utterances.json"); //<-- NOTE: this line should be awaited
    await context.PostAsync($"You have reached {result.Intents[0].Intent}. You said: {result.Query}");
    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
}
```